# Image Exports with Black Background rather than Transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

In attempt to render the following with a transparent background, the image exported is shown with a black background.
[image: Before render with options enabled/disabled]
While the transparent option underneath the Film category is selected, and background images is disabled, it renders normally shown with a transparent background.
[image: When rendered] 
However, when it is saved as an image, it is replaced with a black background
[image: Image with incorrect background]
What can I do to make sure the image itself has a transparent background?

Comment: You also need to select `RGBA` in save page

Comment: What image format are you using? If the image format does not support alpha (like jpg or most video codecs), then you will need to export the alpha channel as a separate mask.